# Unable to display the current status of a process in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I have written below piece of code to achieve my task of exporting printers details on the machine. Below code works without any issues.

Generally, it takes a few seconds or more to generate the printer details file, hence I would like to display the status of this process on a label or text box (like "File is being generated. Please wait..", "File is generated.." etc.)

I'm unable to get the right status on the label with below code. It directly shows the "File is generated" status. But if put messagebox before and after while loop then it works fine.

Any assistance is greatly helpful. Thank you.

```
Label1.Text = "Status: File is being generated. Please wait.."

Dim pPrintBrm As New ProcessStartInfo
pPrintBrm.FileName = "C:\Windows\System32\spool\tools\PrintBrm.exe"
pPrintBrm.Arguments = " " & "-B" & " " & "-F" & " " & 
My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "\Extracted\Printer.PrinterExport"
pPrintBrm.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
Process.Start(pPrintBrm)

Dim exists As Boolean = File.Exists(My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "\Extracted\Printer.PrinterExport")

MessageBox.Show("before while " & exists)

While (exists = "False")

exists = File.Exists(My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "\Extracted\Printer.PrinterExport")

End While

MessageBox.Show("after while " & exists)

If File.Exists(My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "\Extracted\Printer.PrinterExport") Then

Label1.Text = "Status: File is generated"
Else
Label1.Text = "Status: Failed"
End If
```

Comment: That's because you're doing everything on the UI thread, so the `Label` doesn't have a chance to be refreshed before all the code finishes executing.  You need to either do the work on a secondary thread or explicitly `Refresh` the `Label` after setting the `Text` at the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Async/Await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/async/) to keep your app responsive while it is in the loop:

```
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Label1.Text = "Status: File is being generated. Please wait.."

    Dim pPrintBrm As New ProcessStartInfo
    pPrintBrm.FileName = "C:\Windows\System32\spool\tools\PrintBrm.exe"
    pPrintBrm.Arguments = " " & "-B" & " " & "-F" & " " &
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "\Extracted\Printer.PrinterExport"
    pPrintBrm.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    Process.Start(pPrintBrm)

    Dim exists As Boolean
    Do
        Await Task.Delay(250) ' <-- code pauses here, but the UI is still responsive and updates
        exists = File.Exists(My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "\Extracted\Printer.PrinterExport")
    Loop While (Not exists)

    If exists Then
        Label1.Text = "Status: File is generated"
    Else
        Label1.Text = "Status: Failed" ' <-- how can you ever get here with the above loop?!
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that the sub declaration has been marked with "Async".

Answer (score 0):

Use BackgroundWorker component then do this code in DoWork event of Background Worker and show all update status on the label by BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress()